# Consuming web service from a remote computer

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a desktop application built with jdk 6 which publishes web services to be consumed by a web application. So far I've had no problem while both applications are running in the same physical computer, i can access the wsdl without any problem and the web application works with the desktop application just fine. The thing is I cannot access to the services from a remote computer in the same network. The two PCs are connected and can interact. If I run both applications in PC1, from PC2 I can use the webapp through

```
http://PC1:8080
```

I am currently publishing like this:

```
public Publicador(){
 servicios= new Servicios();
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://PC1:8686/servicios", servicios);
}
```

where PC1 is the name of the pc. From PC1, i can see the generated wsdl from the following address, and it's the one I used for the wsimport command:

```
http://PC1:8686/servicios?wsdl
```

But I cannnot from PC2.

Any ideas why it is not visible from outside PC1?

Comment: Firewall? What happens if you browse to that URL from PC 2 in a web browser?

Comment: Firewalls from both computers are down. Thought that could be an issue. The weird thing is i can access the webapp running in PC1, but not the wsdl to run it outside pc1. I get the firefox "cannot conect error" if i try to access the wsdl from pc2

Comment: What's the implementation publishing the WSDL? Tomcat?

Comment: The wsdl is published from a desktop application, the wsdl was generated through the apt command. For that I have mainly two classes, a Publicador (publisher) which is the snippet of code above which runs when the application starts, and makes the wsdl available locally, and a services class, which has the @ WebServices flag and @ WebMethod in each method. It's consumed by a webapp using tomcat.

Comment: But which jax-ws implementation are you using? Sorry to be unclear before. If you have a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem, that would help.

Comment: jax-ws implementation? I'm new with this stuff, I'll try to be a bit more specific to what's the problem I'm having, if that doesn't help I'll try to give you more info. I have a desktop app in pc1 which publishes the services, and i need the webapp to consume them from a different computer, say pc2. The problem is, since the wsdl is not available outside pc1, the webapp in pc2 cannot consume the services. Maybe this was already clear and i don't understand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: The call to `Endpoint.publish` finds some jax-ws implementation and uses that to do the publishing - I'm trying to work out what that is. I can't say I've done any Java web services using this API either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incredible as it may seem, I found the simplest of answers... Instead of publishing as

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://PC1:8686/servicios", servicios);
```

I published as

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8686/servicios", servicios);
```

and that solved it...

Another solution was to get the address to publish from a file, that worked too. I don't know why it didn't hardcoded... I ended up doing it like this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream is = null;
String currenDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String nombreArchivo = currenDir + File.separator + "ubicacion.PROPERTIES";
try {
is=new FileInputStream(nombreArchivo);
prop.load(is);
} catch(IOException ioe) {}

String pc = prop.getProperty("ServiciosWeb");      
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish( pc, servicios);
}
```